# Best method for getting an accurate timestamp?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an app where there is a need for a reliable, accurate timestamp in JavaScript. As such, I would prefer not to rely on the client system time. Although it is likely to be correct, I need something more certain.

I was hoping there was an API available from a well endowed provider such as Google that would allow me to access an accurate timestamp from some server somewhere. I haven't been able to find that, so I came up with another idea: create a tiny dummy file on our server, retrieve it via AJAX and extract our own server's timestamp from response headers:

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'dummy.json',
 complete: function (response) {
   // header is available as a string: response.getAllResponseHeaders();
 }
}
```

Headers:

```
Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2011 14:07:41 GMT
Content-length: 18
Last-modified: Thu, 13 Oct 2011 20:35:28 GMT
Server: Netscape-Enterprise/6.1 AOL
Etag: "0-0-12-0"
Content-type: text/plain
Accept-ranges: bytes
```

Is this not the most ridiculous work-around ever? Am I going crazy? Is there a better solution?

If not could somebody help me write a regex to extract just the date from the above response header string?

edit: forgot to mention the reason why this is a problem is I don't have access to the backend to create some simple service for polling a timestamp from the server or anything like that. I have to do it in JavaScript for this particular application.

Comment: How accurate?  +/-5 seconds?  Down to the millisecond?  You have limited accuracy requesting time from anything really.

Comment: I think it's a clever solution, although as others say succeptible to lag.

Comment: A few seconds or even minutes of lag would be fine for this particular app. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: var headers = req.getResponseHeader("Date");
This will return the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your solution, but there are plenty of web services out there. Google quickly reveals [this service from Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/util/timeservice/V1/getTime.html) and [this one from earthtools](http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm). They all work, it's just a matter of choosing the one that fits best for you.

Answer (score 1):

[This one](http://json-time.appspot.com/) is in JSON format with seperate properties available (seconds etc). You can choose the time zone and also supports JSONP.

Comment: thanks this is the type of thing I am looking for. I will run this guy way over his Appspot bandwidth limit though if I use it for what I'm working on... it is going to get a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the server send a cookie with the current time - that at least would be available in the *initial* request's `document.cookie` property.

Comment: Thanks but I don't have access to make server-side changes at all